# Dojo Mobile 1.7.2 TabBarButton iOS Retina Support

Tags: ios, mobile, dojo, retina-display

Does anyone know if the Dojo mobile TabBarButton (for inclusion in a 1.7.2 TabBar) supports iOS retina icons?  I know CSS media queries are used with JQuery but I can't find information about how to use CSS Media Queries with Dojo Mobile Toolkit.

So in the example below...

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
 .ui-icon-myapp-settings { 
      background: url("settings@2x.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
       background-size: 18px 18px; 
 }
```

"ui-icon-myapp-settings" I think is specific to JQuery.  What would I use to isolate the icon I define for Dojo Mobile TabBarButton?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If dojo used css background image this could be done using "background-size: contain". But because it uses  tag there is nothing you can do.